# Родитель управляет несколькими дочерними процессами .C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, процесс, exec

Пишу класс,где родитель должен управлять несколькими дочерними процессами.Задумка интерфейса состоит в следующем : У класса есть поля pid,cmdline(путь запускаемого процесса),конструктор(тут создаю процесс,в параметре передаю строку),обработчик сигнала(нужен для слежки родителя за дочерними процессами),деструктор(тут убиваем процессы).Проблем несколько :
1)Мне нужно, чтобы 1 родитель следил за множеством дочерних процессов.У меня ,как я понимаю все совершенно иначе:каждый раз создается родитель.
2)Многие процессы не запускаются через gnome-terminal.
3)В любом случае срабатывает обработчик signal_hanlder(хотя не должен из-за бесконечного цикла в том случае,когда создается дочерний процесс).
4)В деструкторе я убиваю,сигнал,я конечно до этого не дошел толком,но есть предположения ,что просто kill(pid,SIGTERM) его не убить.
Столкнулся с такими проблемами....Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef SUBPROCESS_H_
#define SUBPROCESS_H_

class Subprocess {
public:
    Subprocess(const char* name_of_child_process);
    Subprocess(const Subprocess & obj);
    ~Subprocess();
    void Create_Process();
private:
    pid_t pid;
    const char* cmdline;
};
void signal_handler(int signal);

#endif /* SUBPROCESS_H_ */



/*
 * Subprocess.cpp
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <csignal>
#include "Subprocess.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    cout<<"I am a signal handler"<<endl;
    int child_status;
    pid_t pid;
    for(;;)
    {
        pid=waitpid(-1, &child_status, WNOHANG);
        if(pid>0)
        {
            cout <<"Process with pid "<<pid<<" terminated"<<endl;
            pid=fork();
            cout << "Process with pid "<<pid<<"restarted "<<endl;
            break;
        }
        pause();
    }

}

Subprocess::Subprocess(const char* name_of_child_process)
{
    cout<<"Default constructor"<<endl;
    cmdline=name_of_child_process;
    pid=fork();
    if (pid==-1) cout<<"Error ,process not fork"<<endl;
    else if (pid==0) {
        cout <<"I am children process"<<getpid()<<"  My pa_pid "<<getppid()<<endl;
        execlp("gnome-terminal","gnome-terminal","-e",cmdline,NULL);
        cout<<"Child process created with name "<<cmdline<<endl;
        for(;;);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"I am a parent with pid "<<getpid()<<endl;
        signal(SIGCHLD,signal_handler);


    }


}


void Subprocess::Create_Process()
{

}

Subprocess::~Subprocess() {
    kill(pid,SIGTERM);
}

int main()
{

    Subprocess process1("/bin/sh");
    //Subprocess process2("xclock");
    //vector<shared_ptr<Subprocess> > processes;
    //processes.push_back(process1("/bin/sh"));
    //processes.push_back(make_shared<Subprocess>("/bin/sh"));
}
```

Comment: Не очень понял всю вашу задумку (цель) управления процессами, но `signal_handler()` абсолютно не правильна. Эта функция будет вызываться ОС всякий раз, когда завершается какой-либо дочерний процесс. Поэтому бесконечный цикл в ней не нужен. Он приведет к тому, что после ее вызова управление в прерванный родительский процесс уже не вернется. А что вы задумали, вызывая в ней fork, я даже предположить не могу. Кстати,  для ее активации в качестве обработчика достаточно одного вызова `signal`.

Comment: Я буду специально ронять процесс,и задумка заключалась в том,что родитель будет это отслеживать и автоматически поднимать данный процесс.

Comment: 1) Вызывать *fork* в обработчике сигнала - крайне рискованное занятие. Если процесс созданный *fork* тут же завершится, то получится чёрт знает что. 2) Вызов *fork* без последующего анализа pid и вызова функции из семейства *exec* абсолютно бессмысленны.  ВЫ просто создаёте копию родительского процесса. Зачем ?! Он же должен быть один!

Comment: "Многие процессы не запускаются через gnome-terminal." - это что означает ?

Comment: `"задумка заключалась в том,что родитель будет это отслеживать и автоматически поднимать данный процесс"` -- почитайте [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) и [man 7 signal-safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Мне кажется, что непосредственно обработчик сигнала не лучшее место для полной реализации нужной вам функциональности. Возможно, для реализации в linux стоит посмотреть на [man 2 signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) и сделать синхронную обработку в родительском процессе

Comment: C gnome-terminal разобрался,все успешно получилось запустить.В данном коде есть недоработки,постараюсь выложить свое решение чуть позже.Я понял ,что делал что-то бесполезное(просто копировал родительский процесс)

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы желаете запустить (к примеру) пять дочерних процессов, нужно пять раз повтори следующую последовательность действий:

```
pid=fork();
    if (pid==-1) cout<<"Error ,process not fork"<<endl;
    else if (pid==0) {
        cout <<"I am children process"<<getpid()<<"  My pa_pid "<<getppid()<<endl;
        execlp("gnome-terminal","gnome-terminal","-e",cmdline,NULL);
        // Этот код, следующий ПОСЛЕ execlp, не будет выполняться НИКОГДА 
        cout<<"Child process created with name "<<cmdline<<endl;
        for(;;);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"I am a parent with pid "<<getpid()<<endl;
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        Запоминаем pid в списке запущенных процессов 

    }
```

После этого:

1. Повисаем на *wait(...)*
2. Сосокочив с ожидания, по pid, выданному *wait*, определяем, какой именно процесс завершился.
3. Перезапускаем именно этот процесс

Использовать ф-цию *signal* нет нужды. 
Отладьте программу на процессах, которые НЕ создают графическое окружение. Получится - добавляйте запуск гуёвых приложений.